# SQL Server: Computed Column Result Used In Another Computed Column

Tags: sql-server

I know its not possible to have a computed column take into consideration its calculations another computed column. I found out the hard ware with the following error:

```
"is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition."
```

So i have the following data columns, which arent neccessarily important, but just so you understand what I am doing (any other columns referenced are standard non computed columns):

```
HardwareAssetDepreciableValue AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),HardwareAssetPurchaseValue - 
HardwareAssetSalvageValue)

HardwareAssetLifeSpan AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),DATEDIFF(day,HardwareAssetDateInstalled,
HardwareAssetEndOfLifeDate)) / 365
```

They are all calculated and work as expected, however what I am having issues with is a rather complicated set of calculations at best, but wondering if anyone can suggest or help with alternatives to resolving the issue of multiple computed columns.

My query is:

```
HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue AS CASE WHEN HardwareAssetDepreciationMethodID
 = '1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),((HardwareAssetDepreciableValue / HardwareAssetLifeSpan)
/ 365)) WHEN HardwareAssetDepreciationMethodID = '2' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),
HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue + ((1.5 *(1/HardwareAssetLifeSpan))*
HardwareAssetBookValue)/365) ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),
HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue + ((2 *(1/HardwareAssetLifeSpan))
*HardwareAssetBookValue)/365) END
```

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error `is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.` occurs when you have used computed column to calculate another column value...

it seems you have below computed column

`HardwareAssetDepreciableValue`

And then you ,use the same to calculate below computed column

```
THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),((HardwareAssetDepreciableValue / HardwareAssetLifeSpan)
/ 365))
```

you should not do like that..instead ,you should use base calculation

> but wondering if anyone can suggest or help with alternatives to resolving the issue of multiple computed columns.

at present,there are no better alternatives ,one solution i could think of is a view to query the base table and use already existing computed values

Comment: I will look at using a view to get the same result thanks

Answer (score 1):

A computed column is good for a "one off" IMHO.

For something a tad bit complex, I like to create a scalar user defined function, and wrap the "mini logic" in it.

Here is a simple Northwind example.  It doesn't make alot of pratical sense, but demonstrates.

Now, I don't like the below udfExampleUdfTwoDoubleUdfOne idea.  But it could work for you.

Its an idea for the arsenal of tools.  Which is because you asked for alternate ideas.

```
Use Northwind
GO

create function dbo.udfExampleUdfOne(@OrderID as int, @ProductID int, @UnitPrice money )
        returns int
as
begin

declare @returnValue int = 0

select @returnValue = ISNULL(@OrderID,0) + ISNULL(@ProductID,0) + ISNULL(@UnitPrice,0)


return @returnValue;

end;

GO

create function dbo.udfExampleUdfTwoDoubleUdfOne(@udfOneResult int)
        returns int
as
begin

declare @returnValue int = 0

select @returnValue = ISNULL(@udfOneResult,0) * 2


return @returnValue;

end;


GO

SELECT TOP 1000 [OrderID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Discount]
      , MyValueOne = dbo.udfExampleUdfOne(OrderID , ProductID , UnitPrice)
      , MyValueTwoWhichIsActuallyDoubleValueOne = dbo.udfExampleUdfTwoDoubleUdfOne(dbo.udfExampleUdfOne(OrderID , ProductID , UnitPrice))
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details]
```

APPEND

So trying to mimic your example

```
create function dbo.udfComputeHardwareAssetDepreciableValue(@HardwareAssetPurchaseValue int, @HardwareAssetSalvageValue int )
        returns int
as
begin

declare @returnValue int = 0

select @returnValue = ISNULL(@HardwareAssetPurchaseValue,0) - ISNULL(@HardwareAssetSalvageValue,0)


return @returnValue;

end;



create function dbo.udfComputeHardwareAssetLifeSpan(@HardwareAssetDateInstalled int, @HardwareAssetEndOfLifeDate int )
        returns int
as
begin

declare @returnValue int = 0

select @returnValue = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),DATEDIFF(day,@HardwareAssetDateInstalled,
@HardwareAssetEndOfLifeDate)) / 365


return @returnValue;

end;
```

Then write a third UDF that encapsulates your HardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue IF/THEN/CASE logic.

You ~could~ pass in the computed columns into the new udfComputeHardwareAssetAccumulatedDepreciationValue  function as well.

Even if you are new , you should spend a little time struggling with this concept as its a tool in the best to avoid RBAR/CURSORS.

You can get the Northwind db from here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143221(v=sql.105).aspx

Yes, its very old, but simple demos can be created from it.

Comment: ill be honest i think the example you have provided is well out of my current abilities to probably apply, still very much a novice but i really appreciate your time and help and will certainly spend the time to look into understanding exactly what you have helped with and how i can utilise it going forward

Comment: You basically have a function where you "pass-in" every piece of information you need .......... the function takes those input values .... to compute a single output value ........ and return that value.  Since you call it "with" a regular select statement, it performs decently.  I appended my answer some.

Answer (score 0):

you can make both of the columns user defined Function ,  i was looking for it but finally got , the function can access all the columns computed ND NON Computed...

thank you